# Find the width of an image by its index number?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the [Slick Slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) and I'm trying to find the width of the current slide using the `slickCurrentSlide` method. Is it possible to somehow find the width of the slide based on its index number in the array? That is what returns with the following method. This is probably a really basic question, by the way. I'm just getting the hang of things.

```
var currentSlide = $slider.slick('slickCurrentSlide'); // returns an index number
```

Comment: Looks like you could use `$('.slick-active')` to get the current active slide as jq object, which should be the same as `$('.slick-slide').eq(currentSlide);`

Comment: @A.Wolff Well that sure makes things easier. :)